# Sybase GUI Client

Tags: sybase

What are the available Sybase GUI clients for Windows.

I have tried DBVisualizer and RazorSQL any other recommendations. Free preferred

Answer (score 8):

u can try "Interactive SQL" which shipped with Sybase 15 Client, it's better than Sql Advantage, and it's free to download via. Sybase website.

Answer (score 4):

One other solution would be **sqlDeveloper** from oracle (if you are used to it). You can make it work with Sybase databases by downloading the **jTDS driver**. Then you can go to sqlDeveloper and choose **Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> Third Party JDBC driver**. It will work like a charm.

I find it very convinient as i was used to sqlDeveloper, so i can add any driver for any DB provider i want.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a non commercial client [TOAD for sybase](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sybase/default.aspx) 
and a comercial client like [dbArtisan](http://www.embarcadero.com/es/products/dbartisan) that allows you debug of the stored procedures what for me its very usefull.

Answer (score 2):

I like [SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net/), sort of like DBVisualiser but entirely free. It can connect to a lot of databases (that have JDBC drivers) and has a handy datapump/data replication tool, that can also be used in batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Data Studio seems popular with the clients I work with.  But I generally use the tools from Sybase : Interactive SQL (SQL Editor) and Sybase Central (Data Schema, Debugger etc)

Comment: this one looks nice but is quite expensive

Answer (score 0):

Other possible tools could be Squirrel and DBeaver. Both are open-source and free.

Here are some links : dbeaver.jkiss.org 
                     squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net .

SQuirreL SQL Client is a graphical SQL client written in Java that will allow you to view the structure of a JDBC compliant database, browse the data in tables, issue SQL commands etc.

DBeaver will let you do all basic DDL and DML functions, DB object script extraction etc. Various plugins exist e.g DBDiff Plugin which lets you compare objects between two different sessions

Comment: You can improve your answer with links to these two tools and some summary about each one, do you use them? What are they each good at?

Comment: I do use them.  They are free and provide pretty much everything you would expect from a GUI client.  Squirrel  is less robust and tends to crash if you have sessions running into several days, but that was acceptable considering the cost-savings.

Comment: Ok, well what do I expect from a GUI client? Edit your answer and make it more informative to readers with similar issues.... why should they use either of these? How do these tools solve *this* SO problem?

Comment: Here are some links :  http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/     and http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/  .

Comment: It will let you do all basic DDL and DML functions, DB object script extraction etc.  Various plugins exist e.g DBDiff Plugin which lets you compare objects between two different sessions

Comment: Ok, now edit your answer and put this useful info. into your answer `:-p`

Answer (score 0):

Workbench/J is a good choice. It can work with Oracle/Sybase/Informix and other databases.

Setup SQL Workbench/J to connect to sybase in Ubuntu 14.0.4

1. Install SCN SDK "https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/ui/resources/store/html/SolutionDetails.html?pid=0000013451&catID=&pcntry=US&sap-language=EN&_cp_id=id-1417018812660-0"
2. unzip the file.
3. create /opt/sap  and chown sap:sap /opt/sap  -- sap is the owner for software
4. run setup.bin after unzip the linux.tgz
5. In SQL Workbench Setup jdbc connection pointing to "/opt/sap/jConnect-16_0/classes/jconn4.jar"
6. Setup sybase connection URL to be jdbc:sybase:Tds:: 
   e.g. jdbs:sybase:Tds:sybase1:5000

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlDbx personal edition. It is fast and efficient.